# Prove propositional logic by resolution.

Tags: propositional-calculus

Prove $$[(p→q) \wedge (qr→s)]\to [pr→s],$$ which is the same as $$[(\lnot p\lor q) \wedge (\lnot (qr) \lor s)]\to [\lnot (pr) \lor s]$$

I believe it can just be done with algebra rules, but I got stuck at the end.

And this is not a programming question.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Can you give some more context to this question: which rules are you allowed to use (there are many consistent sets of rules)? Also, what have you done already?

Comment: Also, [this link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) might help you typeset your posts.

Comment: Intuitively: We want to prove '$p$ and $r$ imply $s$'. So, assume $p$ and $r$. By $p$ and $p\to q$ we also have $q$, so we have both $q$ and $r$, finally, using $qr\to s$ we arrive to $s$.

Comment: So the problem is like what @user26486 stated: LHS → RHS. But the problem is prove by resolution, which means, correct me if I'm wrong, I have to somehow transform LHS so that it comes out the same as RHS.

Answer (score 0):

We do not have $(\overline{p}\lor q)\wedge (\overline{q\wedge r}\lor s)\equiv \overline{p\wedge r}\lor s$. $\,\text{RHS}\equiv \overline{p}\lor \overline{r}\lor s$.

Assume $s$. Then $\text{RHS}$ is true, but $\text{LHS}\equiv \overline{p}\lor q$, which is not necessarily true.

But we do have $(\overline{p}\lor q)\wedge (\overline{q\wedge r}\lor s)\to\overline{p}\lor \overline{r}\lor s$. I assume that's what you wanted to say - please be more clear next time.

$$\overline{p}\lor \overline{r}\lor s\lor \overline{(\overline{p}\lor q)\wedge (\overline{q\wedge r}\lor s)}$$

$$\stackrel{\text{DeMorg}}\equiv \overline{p}\lor \overline{r}\lor s\lor (p\wedge\overline{q})\lor (q\wedge r\wedge \overline{s})$$

$$\stackrel{\text{Distr}}\equiv p\lor \overline{q}\lor \overline{r}\lor s\lor (q\wedge r\wedge \overline{s})$$

$$\stackrel{\text{Distr}}\equiv p\lor \overline{q}\lor \overline{r}\lor [(s\lor (q\wedge r))\wedge (s\lor \overline{s})]$$

$$\equiv p\lor \overline{q}\lor \overline{r}\lor s\lor (q\wedge r)$$

$$\stackrel{\text{Distr}}\equiv p\lor \overline{r}\lor s\lor \overline{q}\lor r\equiv T\lor p\lor s\lor \overline{q}\equiv T$$

Or simply by observation:

We must have $(\overline{p}\lor q)$. If $\overline{p}$, we're done. Otherwise $q\wedge(\overline{q\wedge r}\lor s)$, which is

$$q\wedge (\overline{q}\lor \overline{r}\lor s)\stackrel{\text{Distr}}\equiv (q\wedge\overline{q})\lor (q\wedge (\overline{r}\lor s))\equiv q\wedge (\overline{r}\lor s),$$

so we must have $\overline{r}\lor s$. If $\overline{r}$, we're done. If $s$, we're done. Or do it like Berci said in the comments.

Comment: Yes I meant LHS → RHS. But the problem is prove by resolution, which means, correct me if I'm wrong, I have to somehow transform LHS so that it comes out the same as RHS.

Comment: @PTN [Steven Taschuk's answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1315115/107671) correctly proves it by resolution. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_%28logic%29#A_simple_example) for what a proof by resolution really is. [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_%28logic%29#Resolution_in_propositional_logic), the more complicated table is just a consequence, since $c\lor a_1\lor \cdots\lor a_{i-1}\lor a_{i+1}\lor\cdots\lor a_n\equiv c\lor (a_1\lor\cdots\lor a_{i-1}\lor a_{i+1}\lor\cdots\lor a_n)$, and similarly $\lnot c\lor b_1\lor\cdots\equiv\lnot c\lor (b_1\lor \cdots)$.

Answer (score 0):

If it's proof by [resolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_%28logic%29) you need, rewrite the premises to $\neg p\vee q$ and $\neg q\vee\neg r\vee s$, then apply resolution on $q$:
$$\begin{array}{ccc}
\neg p\vee q & & \neg q\vee\neg r\vee s \\
\hline
& \neg p \vee \neg r \vee s
\end{array}$$
Then rewrite that conclusion to $p\wedge r\to s$.